# When closing how to specify a new SE site?

Tags: discussion, migration

When closing a question because it belongs on another site, the dialog box (at least on some sites) provide just two or three default SE sites where the problem might be migrated.  How do I add a new such site?

For instance, when trying to close a question posed on mathematics, I wanted to state that it belonged instead on cryptography.SE, but the only alternatives were MathOverflow, Physics, etc.

Comment: For questions about Stack Exchange or one of the Stack Exchange sites, go either to meta.stackexchange.com or the specific site's meta.

Comment: "How do I add a new such site?" - You simply flag the question as, *in need of moderator intervention*, and if the moderator that handles your flag agrees with your conclusion that it should be migrated they will do it.

Comment: What you should not do, is indicate the question is not on topic, then suggest a SE website.  This causes the author of the question to ask the question there, which means the original question, must be either abandoned or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you flag for migration.

Its worth remember a few things though.

If its on topic here, and you're not the OP, chances are we won't move it.

If its *off* topic somehow *and* there's a suitable site *and* its a good question (Cause don't migrate crap is the golden rule of migrations), we'll move it.

Comment: Reference: “As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to that community.  When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask.  **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else.  …” Source: [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others).